# Is there a way to modify an element in an array in a state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to modify an element in the array in a state. lets say I want to modify "id".

```js
class example extends Component {

  state = {
    recipes: [{
      id: 5
    }]
  }
  changeID = (newID, arrayIndex) => {
  
  }
```

What would I need to put in `changeID` to modify id?

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like this:

```
function changeID(ID){
  const { recipes } = this.state;
  const filteredRecipes = recipes.filter(item => item.id === ID);
  
  /*
    Any logic to change the element here!
    You can check if the element exists before doing anything.
  */
  const recipe = filteredRecipes.shift();
  const updatedRecipe = { ...recipe, id:6 }

  //And if you want to update the state...
  const updatedRecipes = [ ...recipes, updatedRecipe ];
  this.setState({ recipes: updatedRecipes });
}
```

Comment: Yeap. Great answer!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `setState` combined with `map` (since your state is an array) to modify a given element with a specific `id`

```
 changeID = (id, index) =>{
     this.setState(prev =>{
         return {
             recipes : prev.recipes.map((recipe, i) =>{
                 if(index === i) return {...recipe, id}
                 return recipe
             })
             
         }
     })
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

In React, state should be readonly.  To modify a value within an array, you should create a new array with just the one element updated.

```js
class example extends Component{

  state={
        recipes: [
          {id: 5}
        ]
    }
  changeID = (newID,arrayIndex)=>{
      // create a shallow copy of the recipe with an updated id
      const newRecipe = { ...recipes[arrayIndex], id: newID }; 
      const newRecipes = recipes
         .slice() // shallow copy the array
         .splice(arrayIndex, 1, newRecipe); // replace the element at arrayIndex with new Recipe
      this.setState({ recipes: newRecipes });
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your code:

```
class Example extends Component{
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { recipes: [{ id: 5 }] };
  }

  changeID = (newID, arrayIndex) => {
    let { recipes } = this.state;
    recipes[arrayIndex].id = newID;

    this.setState({ recipes: recipes }, () => console.log(this.state.recipes));
  };
}
```

Here is the live working solution: [Visit to see](https://codesandbox.io/s/upbeat-bird-i9be0?file=/src/App.js:102-384)

Happy coding :)

Comment: Doesn't this directly modify state?

Answer (score -1):

You can change array values by using the assignment operator `=` and index lookup `[]`. E.g.

```
let arr = [3,4,5];
arr[0] = 0; 
arr; // 0,4,5
```

For your example, that's:

```js
let state = {
  recipes: [{
    id: 5
  }]
};


let changeId = (newId, arrayIndex) =>
  state.recipes[arrayIndex].id = newId;

changeId(4, 0);
console.log(state);
```

Comment: Be careful, you're mutating the state

Comment: The function's called `changeId`, it implies mutation.

Comment: Yeap, but since the question is inside React's scope you need to follow the core principle of immutability. It's perfect fine to mutate an array like you've done so. But use a new reference `[...prevState]`